# Exception FatalThrowableError Class 'app\models\category' not found

Tags: laravel-6

I can't understand where I made a mistake. The following is the error.

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Class
>   'app\models\category' not found

```
class homepage extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        print_r(category::all());
        die();

        return view('frontend.homepage', $categories);
    }
}
```

Error in line. `print_r(category::all());die();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line `use app\models\category;` to this `use App\Models\Category;`

```
public function index(){

    print_r(Category::all());die();
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('frontend.homepage',compact('categories'));

}
```